# Schedule task for specific time from spring 4 web mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron

I am building a Spring 4 Rest API for a trade automation site.

An http request will contain some info along with a date-time. After inserting these info into database (using hibernate), I need to **dynamically create a new cron job which will access these db info and do something**. The cron job **must be executed at the time specified above**.

So there wont be a fixed cron expression, also the cron task must access my DAO layer annoted with *@Repository*.
Even after referring a lot of post in stack and other blog, which tells about *@Scheduled*, *Spring-Quartz integration*, I couldn't find out a solution for my specific need.

Java/Annotation configuration is preferred.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Trigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html) and [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) interfaces. Example below. To cancel job in the future it will be needed to store `ScheduledFuture` instance.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }
}

@Controller
public class TriggerService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    private DAOService db;

    private ScheduledFuture job;        

    @GetMapping("/task1")
    @ResponseBody
    public void triggerMyTask(@RequestParam String cronExpression) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.info(new Date());
                /**
                 * here You can do what You want with db
                 * using some DAOService
                 */         
                db.count();
            }
        };

        /**
         * cancel current task if You need
         */
        if(job != null) {
           job.cancel(true);
        }

        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cronExpression);
        job = scheduler.schedule(runnable, trigger);
    }
}
```

You can pass cron expression for example like that:

```
http://localhost:8080/task1?cronExpression=0/5%20*%20*%20*%20*%20*
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Saved my day!!

Comment: Not the Trigger interface, but **org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler.schedule(Runnable arg0, Date arg1)**
method actually worked for me.


`final Long key = transDao.saveTransaction(transObj);

  
  
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {          
  
            
   private long id = key;

            public void run() {

             

             taskService.executeTask(id);

            }

        };`


The taskService is autowired and it is transactional so that i can access my Transaction object with the _id_ value.

Comment: `scheduler.schedule(runnable, exeTime);` where exeTime is exactly 'java.util.Date' from http request

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use something like this: https://ha-jdbc.github.io/apidocs/net/sf/hajdbc/util/concurrent/cron/CronThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Although this may answer the question consider posting some more details and sample code as well.

Comment: @Yuri Thanks for your reply. But this not the exact answer for my need